# restricting the process started by System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: .net, security, c#-4.0, process

i have created a process using the Process class. now i need to restrict what all this new process can access like the permission for accessing internet,l or a special directory.
how can it be done.
my code so far is like this.

```
Process p = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executablePath) { 
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                }
            };
            p.Start();

            var outputStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;
            var inputStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
            var errorStreamReader = p.StandardError;

            p.WaitForExit();

            string output = outputStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            string s = "";
```

Comment: Your code can deadlock on `p.WaitForExit()` if the output streams get filled.

Comment: yes.. i missed it. thankx for pointing out this. but considering i wont be getting that much of data through the process. i dont it wud be an issue

Comment: Is it a .net process? Is it yours or a  3rd Party's. Is it within scope for you to do this. Should be up to the user/admin to impose this sort of security restriction.

Comment: the path that wud be executed wud be decided on runtime and it will be some1 elses console app but the system it will run on is mine and obsly the code is mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict a process by starting it with a restricted user account - you need pass in the [`UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username.aspx) and [`Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password.aspx) (which is a [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)) to the process either in the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) or directly on the `Process` before starting it.

Comment: yeah.. thankx for this. but the system on which this will run. creating a user wud hav to be done progrmatically on every recycle that wudnt be cool enuf.. i hope there must be some system in windows or .net to take care of what a process is accessing.

Comment: @ParvSharma - Not that I am aware. The process being spawned is completely separate. And that detail is really something you should have in the question.

Comment: nd also this might require me to load the user profile everytime would need to execute some console app.. that wud take up lot of resources.

Comment: hmm. comparing to appDomains there are systems in place to restrict what a peice of code is accessing inside an app domin.